# Mod_WSGI can't find python module

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I've looked at every related post I can find here without luck.

Environment is AWS EC2 and I validated that basic html works, so security groups are good.

I get the following error when a client makes a request for the index.

**error.log**

```
AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
mod_wsgi (pid=26150): Attach interpreter ''.
mod_wsgi (pid=26150): Adding '/var/www/html/webServer/venv/bin/' to path.
mod_wsgi (pid=26150): Adding '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
mod_wsgi (pid=26152, process='', application='ip-172-31-27-137.us-east-2.compute.internal|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/html/webServer/webhook.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=26152): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/webServer/webhook.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=26152): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/webServer/webhook.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/webServer/webhook.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
     from webhook import webhook as application
  File "/var/www/html/webServer/webhook.py", line 54, in <module>
     from flask import Flask, request
  ImportError: No module named flask
```

**000-default.conf**

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess webhook python-path=/var/www/html/webServer/venv/bin:/var/www/html/webServer:/home/ubuntu/webServer/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/webServer/webhook.wsgi

    <Directory webServer>
        WSGIProcessGroup webServer
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**webhook.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/webServer')

from webhook import webhook as application
```

from **webhook.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
webhook = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the Flask web server
    webhook.run()
```

My directory structure is:
app is located in home dir *~/webServer*
with a ln to */var/www/html*
so path is */var/www/html/webServer/*

contents of webServer:

```
[webServer]ls
venv  webhook.py  webhook.wsgi
```

I've brought up python cli and verified that I can import flask

```
[webServer]python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>> exit()

[webServer]sudo python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
```